# Have metals's "electron sea" electrons effect on x-ray diffraction?

Tags: diffraction, electronic-band-theory, metals, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

Can it be possible that there is no effect come from the "electron sea" because of there is no net electron flow, or that flow creates a fuzziness in results?

Comment: Whilst this is not my field, I'm pretty sure that metal electron "seas" result in definite structure in x-ray diffraction patterns because the wavefunctions of the delocalized electrons have definite, periodic structure. "Sea" is an often used, but probably misleading word.

Comment: Indeed, as @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance says, the sea is electrons in Bloch states that satisfy the requirements of the underlying lattice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electrons in metals are described quantum mechanically by Bloch waves $$\psi(\vec r)=u_{\vec k}(\vec r)\exp{i(\vec k·\vec r)}$$ where $u_{\vec k}(\vec r)=u_{\vec k}(\vec r+\vec R)$, $\vec R$ is a lattice vector, has the periodicity of the crystal lattice. Therefore, the location probability of the electrons and thus their average density is given by $$ \psi^*(\vec r)·\psi(\vec r)=|\psi(\vec r+\vec R)|^2$$ has also the periodicity of the lattice. Thus x-ray scattering from electrons in a metal including from conduction electrons is determined by the lattice structure.